# Dynamic refs using ref callback method

Tags: react-native

How do you suppose setting a dynamic ref now?
Im getting an error `cannot set property of 'test' undefined`, if I use

```
<View ref={(ref) => this.someRef['test'] = ref;}/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to set `this.someRef` to an array or object before assigning a property to it.

```
this.someRef = [];
or
this.someRef = {};
```